# How to remove programms in /opt properly

Tags: software-installation, software-uninstall

I have removed programs that were installed in opt/... removed with rm -r {path}. But I get the problem from the installer that the program is already installed in /opt/....
My fear is that I have not finally removed the program.
Maybe someone can help me would be very happy.
Jakob

Comment: I understand that the program has its own installer? So that installer should provide also a way to uninstall the program. You removed the program but you did not remove some information that the installer stores somewhere about the program being installed, so the installer still thinks the program is installed. Check the program's documentation how to remove these "leftovers". Nobody can help you more without knowing what particular program this is and how it was installed.

Answer (score 1):

Before removing the files in /opt/ have a look in the directory. There is an "uninstaller" or a "readme" in there with instructions on how to uninstall or remove.

But since those are tarballs I would assume it will indeed be:

```
rm -rf /opt/{software_versionnumber}/
```

There is possibly 1 other file you need to remove and that is the program that connects the software to the system. That could be a script you moved or symlinked to /bin or /usr or a systemd service. Those do not work after removing /opt but better to get rid of that one too.